# Migrating MySQL table records from dev to QA to prod

Tags: mysql, database, devops, database-migration

**Use case:** We have come across one scenario where we need to migrate the tables/records in a table from one environment (e.g. dev) to another environment (e.g. QA/Test). RDS (MySQL) server is different for both dev and QA environment.

**Problem Statement:** We need to migrate one table or selective records from a table from dev to QA (assuming database and table is already created in QA environment). Before migrating the table/records we need to make some update to the columns which holds environment specific details like vpc_id, subnet_id etc.

**Approach we had tried:** using mysqldump utility, we created sql file containing insert statements and then we manually updated the vpc_id and subnet_id column values in insert statements. Once sql file is updated manually, we executed the sql dump file into QA environment.

**Need help:** How to create an automated solution to perform this task? there can be multiple scenarios like - record already exists in the QA table, record exists in QA table but few columns are updated while migrating from dev.

Please let me know if more details are required on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a different approach: use DB migrations scripts in all environments, and not transfer certain data between environments. In this way, you can customize data from environment variables or some config file for each environment.